# i want to parse json response received in react native using axios

Tags: reactjs, native

```
{"status":1,"message":"Login Successfully. ","info":[{"uid":"12","gender":"Female","name":"priya","sexual":"Straight","relationship":"Single","lookingfor":"Anything Interesting","email":"priya@gmail.com","dob":"Oct 4, 2019","location":"","latitude":"18.520430299999997","longitude":"73.8567437","income":"20L - 30L","image":"..\/post_image\/15719084821049236369.png","yourself":"If Fucut Get\n","occupation":"ivggovhboyvrx","gover_id":"..\/post_image\/1571908482858647323.png","face":"..\/post_image\/1571908482919112539.png","income_proof":"..\/post_image\/15719084821838650906.png","status":"Rejected","linkedin_id":""}]}
```

My response like this

Comment: you can use response like this way `console.log(response.status)` and will output the result

Comment: How can i parse info array

Answer (score 0):

You can use your json response like this

```
console.log(response.status)
```

For array you can use

```
response.info.forEach(info => {
 console.log(info.uid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Parse JSON response you can you `JSON.parse()`

`JSON.parse(string to be parse)`

in your ex. it would be like this 
first you need to be JSON.stringify(your string)
then you can parse Json data like this

```
let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"status":1,"message":"Login Successfully. ","info":[{"uid":"12","gender":"Female","name":"priya","sexual":"Straight","relationship":"Single","lookingfor":"Anything Interesting","email":"priya@gmail.com","dob":"Oct 4, 2019","location":"","latitude":"18.520430299999997","longitude":"73.8567437","income":"20L - 30L","image":"..\/post_image\/15719084821049236369.png","yourself":"If Fucut Get\n","occupation":"ivggovhboyvrx","gover_id":"..\/post_image\/1571908482858647323.png","face":"..\/post_image\/1571908482919112539.png","income_proof":"..\/post_image\/15719084821838650906.png","status":"Rejected","linkedin_id":""}]}
))

console.log(data.info)
```